# Change all link states same color css

Tags: css

I have a spanned class called "tomato".

My css is:

```
.tomato a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
.tomato a:visited {color:#FF0000;}  /* visited link */
.tomato a:hover {color:#FF0000;}  /* mouse over link */
.tomato a:active {color:#FF0000;}  /* selected link */
```

Is there a way I can combine all these into a smaller piece of code? (I want the link to be red in all states)

Comment: [Similar question, with (IMO) better answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303440/setting-avisited-link-to-same-state-as-alink-and-ahover)

Comment: You forgot a:focus state

Comment: Use SASS http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is the `shortest`, I don't think you can do it any shorter than:

```
.tomato a:link, .tomato a:visited, .tomato a:hover, .tomato a:active { color:#FF0000; }
```

OR

```
.tomato { a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color:#FF00000; } }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the second one a valid CSS syntax?

Comment: @GraceShao, No. Some CSS preprocessors support that syntax (LESS, SCSS), but the compiled output is the same as the first example.

Comment: Don't for got FOCUS state.

Comment: @MatějKříž Focus is only for form elements. Like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc.

Comment: @lino4000 no, its not true. How you call that state when you use keyboard to find a link? Yes man - it IS :focus sate. Try you TAB key on this http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css2/sec05-11-03.htm

Comment: ok, don't forget `:focus`, but also please don't make it the same color/style as the others.  How will I know which link I have used to keyboard to navigate to? :)

Answer (score 13):

```
.tomato a:link,
.tomato a:visited,
.tomato a:hover,
.tomato a:active {
    color:#F00;
}
```

Note, the color HEX could be abbreviated, too. :)

If you choose to use a CSS framework to organize your CSS such as LESS, it could be much simpler than the above:

```
.tomato {
   a:link,
   a:visited,
   a:hover,
   a:active {
       color:#F00;
   }
}
```

Comment: Good, but it still repeats tomato...is there any way to remove the repeated tomatos?

Comment: @David19801 See my updated answer about LESS. That could be one option.

Comment: Why is FOCUS state missing?

Answer (score 6):

It is actually best to use [the attribute selector](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/attribute-selector-css-selector/). In this case it would be:

```
.tomato a[href]{color:#F00;}
```

*or if you must:*

```
.tomato [href]{color:#F00;}
```

Comment: Is this standards compliant, so I can depend on this not changing? It's convenient for styling links that should never change.

Comment: As of [MozDev Standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)  Desktop Basic support: Chrome (Yes) || Edge (Yes) || Firefox (Gecko)1.0 (1.7 or earlier) || IE 7+ || Opera 9+ || Safari 3